# Laravel public/index.js file is missing

Tags: laravel

I'm at a complete loss here.

After clearing caches and running the following commands the index.php is missing from public/ folder.

Commands I run:

```
npm install
composer install
npm run prod
```

However public/index.php is missing - how can I generate this file?

```
ls public/
css  fonts  images  js  mix-manifest.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this problem is caused by some antiviruses. I do not really know why that file was removed, but laravel public/index.php file is a standard file that looks like this:

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

It is not an ideal way of doing it, but you can just create an index.php in the public folder and paste there the code snippet above.

Comment: Ah I see. So this file is always static and is not generated by anything. I thought this was kind of dynamic to my site. Thanks for your help!